# how to bind objects created by function-constructors in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, model, angularjs-scope

I want, my model in the controller, to be not a plain object like `Number`,`Boolean`,`String`, `Object`,`Array`, but an object created by function-constructor.

Is it possible in AngularJS?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vc4df/) is my html:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
   <input ng-model="model.text" type="text"/>
</body>
```

and my script:

```
angular.module('MyApp',[]).
constant('MyModel',function(){
    var MyModel = function(text){
        this.text = text;
    };

    return MyModel;
}).
controller('MyController',
           [
               '$scope',
               'MyModel',
               function(
                   $scope,
                   MyModel
               ){
    //Does not work               
    $scope.model = new MyModel('dummy text');
    //Works
    //$scope.model = {text:'dummy text'};                   
}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `constant` doesn't need to be wrapped in a function...

```
angular.module('MyApp',[]).
constant('MyModel',function(text){
        this.text = text;
}).

// ...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S5VXv/

Answer (score 1):

The `constant` is immutable, to create your own-function-constructor use `Factory`.

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])
  .factory('MyModel',function(){
    var MyModel = function(text){
      this.text = text;
    };
    return MyModel;
});
```

[Here is docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe)

Comment: I am new to Angular. Can you give an advice, what is the best way to create reusable classes, not singletons?

Comment: All Services in Angular are singletons. But I think they are what you are definitely looking for. Here is demo to get deferences between service, factory, provider: http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/PxdSP/14/